# Why doesn't the compiler raise an error for spark column expression not being of BooleanType?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have the following scenario:

```
     import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}
     import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

     case class A(name: String)
     val df = List(A("sasha"),A("")).toDF
     // deliberately writing a non boolean expression
     def getFilterExpr: Column = regexp_replace(col("name").isNotNull && col("name") === "sasha" ,"","")

     object Test { def Filter(df:DataFrame):DataFrame = df.filter(getFilterExpr) }
```

The above compiles though `getFilterExpr` is not of `BooleanType`. Only when `Filter(df)` is invoked spark Analysis exception would be thrown.

My question is,

1. Is there any way to have compile time checks here ?
2. Also I intend on having separate method for returning a filter expression, using `Column`(as done above). Is that a good way of doing it ? My doubt arises because `Column` encapsulates an `Expression` and when building a composite expression the result is a `Column` not an expression, which feels bit unintuitive to me.

Comment: Spark **DataFrames** are untyped, that means all errors will be on runtime. If you want something more safe, you can use **Datasets** instead. In this case the only possible runtime error would be when reading the data _(which will be the first step of the code, thus not so bad)_. The down side is that you had to model all your data using cases classes, which may be tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I doubt this is possible. Let's consider you load a `DataFrame` from a parquet file and apply some filter based on one of its columns:

```scala
val df = spark.read.parquet("path_to_dataframe")
df.filter(col("a_column_in_the_parquet"))
```

The result of this will totally depend on the column in the parquet. If it is a boolean column, everything will go well. If it is not a boolean you will get an error. There is no way of knowing the type of the column in compile time (and in this case, it may change between executions if the parquet file changes). So no, you cannot get a compile time error here.

2. I don't see any problem on having something like this:

```scala
def getFilterExpression: Column = ???
```

and I think it will be a good idea if the filter expression is something complex.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because `getFilterExpr` doesn't return a boolead, but rather a Column as you defined it. The filter serves to filter values that doesn't match a given condition out, so it must return `true` if you want to keep a value and `false` if not.

An example of a valid `filter` usage (I don't know spark, so I'll pretend you didn't call `toDF`):

```scala
df.filter(a => !a.name.isEmpty)
```

This filter will keep all instances that are not empty. Judging from your code, there's a high chance that you intended to use `map` rather than `filter`.